# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout / Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, model-view-controller

I have been reading the different answers here on stackoverflow and on this blog post and tried to implement their solutions but I am still getting the error. The code is from a yt tutorial. I hope someone can help me. Thanks

Error E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

My Adapter

This is my Main Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), IDrinkLoadListener {

    lateinit var drinkLoadListener: IDrinkLoadListener
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        init()
        loadDrinkFromFirebase()

    }

    private fun loadDrinkFromFirebase() {
        val drinkModels : MutableList<DrinkModel> = ArrayList()
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("Drink")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (drinkSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                        val drinkModel = drinkSnapshot.getValue(DrinkModel::class.java)
                        drinkModel!!.key = drinkSnapshot.key
                        drinkModels.add(drinkModel)
                    }
                    drinkLoadListener.onDrinkLoadSuccess(drinkModels)
                } else
                    drinkLoadListener.onDrinkLoadFailed("Drink items not exist")
            }


            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                drinkLoadListener.onDrinkLoadFailed(error.message)

            }
        })

    }


    private fun init() {
        drinkLoadListener = this

        val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
        recycler_drink.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
        recycler_drink.addItemDecoration(SpaceItemDecoration())

    }

    override fun onDrinkLoadSuccess(drinkModelList: List<DrinkModel>?) {
        val adapter = MyDrinkAdapter(this,drinkModelList!!)
        recycler_drink.adapter = adapter


    }

    override fun onDrinkLoadFailed(message: String?) {
        Snackbar.make(mainLayout,message!!,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

class SpaceItemDecoration : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect,
        view: View,
        parent: RecyclerView,
        state: RecyclerView.State
    ) {
        if(parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view) % 2 != 0)
        {
            outRect.top= 25
            outRect.bottom= -25
        }else outRect.top = 0

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because the adapter is attached to the recycler after an asynchronous operation on `onDrinkLoadSuccess`

You can attach the adapter to the recycler during `onCreate` and then the `onDrinkLoadSuccess` update it with the data.

The `ListAdapter` class has a `submit` method for it. If you are using plain recycler is usually something like this:

```
Recycler ... {
        private val dataList = mutableListOf()

         fun update(list: List<YourType>) {
                   dataList.clear()
                   dataList.addAll(list)
                   notifyDataDetChanged() //important updates the UI
          }
}
```

There are more specific updates methods like `notifyItemRangeChanged`, etc.

Also there are helpers for finding difference in the data sets `DiffUtil.ItemCallback`